# Access Connection String From File Generated by Server.Execute

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, filesystemobject

I have a file `header.asp` that has an server side include `head.asp`. Inside `head.asp` my connection to my database is created and is accessible from the `header.asp` file and pages that use the `header.asp` file as an server side include (in this case my `core.asp` file). Inside `core.asp` I have the following:

```vb
if request.querystring("page") = "" then
  response.write("<p>No data to load</p>")
else
  page = request.querystring("page")
  set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  FileName = "../Pages/" & page & ".asp"
  if fso.FileExists (server.mappath(FileName)) then 
    Server.Execute(FileName)
  else
    response.write("<p>Could not validate page. Try again.</p>")
  end if
end if
```

This executes just fine and the proper page renders inside the `core.asp` file. My issue, is that the connection string (from `head.asp`) is not available to the file being called from `Server.Execute`. Thus, I cannot run database queries, etc. on this page unless I were to instantiate the object anew. Is there any way to use the object created?

If I have not explained this properly, I will expound as I am able given my intermediate experience level.

Comment: What is the reason behind the use of `Server.Execute`? Is it you trying to mask the URL of your ASP pages? If so have you thought about using `Server.Transfer` to give you the same effect without the need for the `Scripting.FileSystemObject`?

Comment: No, it's not for domain masking. The goal was to dynamically load pages into a common "core" page. I like the net result, just having trouble with the "loaded" page accessing the connection object.

Comment: If that is your goal then why don't you just do include page in side if-- else statement? like that: <%if something then%> <!include some file><% else do what ever here..?

Answer (score 0):

Assign this object to a session variable and you can access it from any page you like...

```
Session("MyConnectionObj")= CONN
```

CONN is your instantiated connection object on the page where you instantiate your connection originally. And in your executed file just call

```
 set NewCONN=Session("MyConnectionObj")
 RS.Open strSql ,NewCONN,1,1
```

where strSql is your SQL, RS is your recordset etc... Obviously if you calling the stored procedure, it will look slightly different but you get the point.

Edited to show that object have to be declared and set before one using it. As I see at least one "expert" did not know that.

Edited base on comments from Window Frog:

> did you try it like that:

```
<%
if request.querystring("page") = "" then
  response.write("<p>No data to load</p>")
else
  page = request.querystring("page")
  set fso = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
  FileName = "../Pages/" & page & ".asp"
  if fso.FileExists (server.mappath(FileName)) then%> 
   <!--#include file="<%=FileName %>" -->
 <% else
    response.write("<p>Could not validate page. Try again.</p>")
  end if
end if
%>
```

Comment: Couple of things one if you're assigning an object you need `Set Session("MyConnectionObj") = CONN` second, don't do that. Storing the `ADODB.Connection` in a `Session` object is a huge overhead and waste of resource not to mention you maintain a connection to your database for the life of the session.

Comment: Think you might find this interesting [In Classic asp, can I store a database connection in the Session object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/90100/692942).

Comment: did I said that this is a good idea? No I did not but man asking how to do that and if he have need I show him how. By the way I am using that on the site most of you used at least once in your life time when you bought online tickets for movie or some other events... So far no single complaint about site been unresponsive or slow...

Comment: Probably doesn't get a lot of traffic. If you know it isn't a good idea why suggest it? The OP wants a way to reference his connection throughout the ASP application, you can do this by storing the connection string in an application variable that way it is assessable throughout the app and the connection can be instantiated as needed rather then being instantiated for the whole session.

Comment: Probably not, that would explain why company in SP100 and not in SP500 list. I would not suggest anything which I did not used successfully on my own sites.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to answer #1, if I've followed the logic correctly, I'm attempting to create the connection object at the application level (global.asa):

```
Sub Application_OnStart() 
dim oConn, connectstr
set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
connectstr = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=theServer; DATABASE=theDatabase; UID=theUserID; PWD=thePassword"
oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 5
oConn.Open connectstr
Application("con") = oConn
end Sub

</script>
```

Attempting to access the object like so from my page that includes the global.asa as an IIS:
    qryAdmin = "select * from table"
    set rsAdmin = Application("con").execute(qryAdmin)

The results are the same. I receive the "Object required" error. Any glaring errors that could be causing this?

Comment: difference between Application and session variables is session object get terminated once session is closed while application object hang around until either IIS reset or special call place to set that object to nothing. In case of database connection, especially if you do not using pooling there, that connection will stay open until database server terminate it for inactivity. While leaving your database wide open for anyone smart enough. Do you want that on your server?Usage should be like that:set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") <br> set oConn=Application("con")

Comment: Do not do that, instead `connectstr` should be stored in your `Application("con")` variable then use that to create your connection when needed.